# Add unique values to a column retrieved from multiple tables in PowerBI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I currently have two tables (Excel sheets) related to each other in PowerBI:

1. Inventory; columns (Article number, description, quantity, sumOfQuantityReceived)
2. MaterialsReceived; columns (Article number, quantityReceived, DateReceived)

The tables are related to each other with an one (Inventory) to many (materialsReceived) relationship, as shown below.

[image: Relationship]

However, the Inventory table currently only shows the Article numbers that are present in the Inventory table and will not automatically add a new row with article number if there is a new one present in the MaterialsReceived table.

For example: The inventory list currently contains the following information

[image: Inventory list]

While there is a new article number present in the MaterialsReceived table (article number: 969686)

[image: Materials Received]

So my question is now: How can I create a new table in PowerBI that retrieves the unique article numbers from both tables and adds them to a new column.

In this situation, the new table would contain one column with 4 rows (456982, 456987, 556987 & 969686)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

```
Uniq_Article_Number_Table =
FILTER (
    DISTINCT (
        UNION (
            VALUES ( inventory[article number] ),
            VALUES ( 'Material Received'[article number] )
        )
    ),
    [article number] <> BLANK ()
)
```

[image: code snippet]